# Apache remains stopped in Ampps windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, ampps

To use an open source software on GitHub it was recommended to use Ampps.
I installed Ampps on Windows 10. Then installed Apache, MySQL, and PHP 7.1.
I can open Ammps and start MySQL but Apache remains stopped.

I tried to run \Ampps\apache\bin\httpd.exe in the command prompt and recieved this error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 144 of C:/Program Files/Ampps/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file 'C:/Program Files/Ampps/apache/conf/ssl_crt/server.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

It's right, I can't find any ssl_crt folders in conf, let alone server.crf file.
I'd like to know why this file is missing.
Is there any issues with my installation process?
How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many inspections, I found that the problem was with my laptop lacking IIS URL Rewrite Module2.
I installed IIS URL Rewrite Module2, changed Apache's configuration to listen to port 8080 instead of 80, and everything worked like a charm.